# Show that a system of non-homogeneous diff. eq does not have a particular solution of the form $x=e^{ct}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been at this problem for a couple of hours now, this is one of the problems in the textbook which I am practicing for my midterm tomorrow.

Here's the problem:

> Given a system of non-homogeneous differential equation of the form: 
>   $\vec{x}' = A\vec{x} + \vec{v}e^{\lambda t}$, where $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of A with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Suppose also that $A$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors $\vec v_1,...,\vec v_n$ with distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ respectively.
>
> (a) Show that this has no particular solution of the form: $\psi(t)=\vec{a}e^{\lambda t}$,
>
> Hint: since $\{\vec v_1,....,\vec v_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ write $\vec{a}=a_1\vec v_1+...+a_n\vec v_v$.

Here is what I have done so far:

Assume particular solution of the form: $\psi=\vec{a}e^{\lambda t}$, then:
$\psi'=\vec{a}\lambda e^{\lambda t}$.

Plug these into the original equation and doing some simplification yields:
$\vec{a}(A-\lambda I)=-\vec{v}$

I know that the matrix ($A-\lambda I$) does not have an inverse because $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}=\frac{adjugate(A-\lambda I)}{det(A-\lambda I)}$, since since $\lambda$ comes from: $det(A-\lambda I)=0$, therefore $(A-\lambda t)^{-1}=\frac{adjugate(A-\lambda I)}{0}$ which cannot be computed, so you cannot find $\vec{a}$, since you cannot find $\vec{a}$, you cannot guess a particular solution of the form $\psi=\vec{a}e^{\lambda t}$.

But how do I show that particular solution of the form $\psi=\vec{a}e^{\lambda t}$ cannot be used using the hint provided.

Thank you.

[image: The actual question]

Comment: There seems to be some crucial hypothesis about $v$, $\lambda$ and $A$, that are missing from your post. For example, why is $A-\lambda I$ supposed to be non invertible?

Comment: I have edited the question for clarification of why i think $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ doesn't exist

Comment: "since $\lambda$ comes from: $det(A-\lambda I)=0$" This is the crucial missing hypothesis: you are assuming that $\lambda$ in the RHS of the differential equation is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$. However, (a) as stated is still wrong since, for some specific vectors $v$, there will exist some vectors $a$ such that $\lambda a=Aa+v$. Still no question here, sorry.

Comment: I think I accidentally might have missed a crucial information, which is the vector $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of A with eigenvalue $\lambda$. My appologies, this fact was stated in the original question, but I forgot to type it in.

Comment: The hint seems to assume more information than given in the task, in that the $n$ eigenvalues are distinct, that is, each eigenvalue is simple. Please check if there was something to that effect in the task description. Or is $n$ different from $N$, then please use that consistently.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely forgot **a lot** of pieces. May I suggest that next time, you try to avoid this unpleasant phase? As for me, I am not sure that I still want to get interested...

Comment: Also, respect that the matrix-vector product is non-commutative, $\vec a(A−λI)$ is not defined for column vectors $\vec a$.

Comment: I really do apologize for the unpleasantness as its's 3 in the morning, however this time I have pasted a screenshot of the actual question from the book.

Comment: So $A$ is completely diagonalizable. Can you do the task if you assume that $A$ is a diagonal matrix? The hint essentially asks you to transform the problem to such a diagonal form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation that you almost correctly derived, $$(A−λI)\,\vec a=-\vec v,$$ along with the task construction, tells you that
$$
\vec v\in \ker (A−λI)\cap \text{im}(A−λI).
$$
This actually is possible for non-simple eigenvalues, for instance consider
$$
\vec x{\,}'=\pmatrix{λ&1\\0&λ}\,\vec x+\vec e_1\,e^{λt}
$$
then $\vec a=-\vec e_2$ gives a solution $\vec x(t)=\vec a\,e^{λt}$.

However, by the corrected assumptions all eigenvalues in your task are simple.